# Facilitating an anonymous video call between a client and a listener

Tags: android, ios, windows, macos, twilio

I'm trying to validate an idea with a MVP (Minimum Viable Product).
I have a list of Listeners who have access to a Laptop or a Smartphone and list of Clients who only have access to a Smartphone (IOS or Android).

How can I facilitate a 1-1 ANONYMOUS video chat between a Client and a Listener? Anonymous means Client or Listener can't see each other's personal info like email or phone number.

The process looks something like this: A client texts me and requests a conversation with a Listener. Based on my metrics I pick a listener and "ideally" send a link to both of them where they can immediately see and talk to each other.
Google hangouts is not a good option as it's not totally anonymous and requires an account along with their App installed on the Phone.

Or the solution could be even simpler If I could provide a Client with a proxy phone number associated to a specific listener so that they could have a Facetime call with them, but I'm not sure if it's possible since Facetime calls are based on iCloud accounts which to my knowledge can't be proxied.

Any suggestions would be appreciated and I'm also open to hearing suggestions on how to use the new Twilio video service.

Thanks so much!

Please let me know if this is not the correct place to post this sort of question. I wasn't sure if it belongs to startups.stackexchange.com as it does need an input from experienced professionals.

Comment: take a look at AOL video chat, http://o.aolcdn.com/aim/video/5_20_2011_a/VideoChatApp.html

Answer (score 0):

appear.in or talky.io services are exactly what I needed.